# Sum Cells with Same Date

Tags: python, pandas

I am a complete noob at this Python and Jupiter Notebook stuff. I am taking an Intro to Python Course and have been assigned a task to do. This is to extract information from a .csv file. The following is a snapshot of my .csv file titled "feeds1.csv"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0HLl.png

I can import the .csv into Jupyter Notebook, and have tried groupby function to sort it. But it won't work due to the fact that column also has time in it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("feeds1.csv")
```

I need it to output as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4slJ5.png

The ultimate goal would be to create a csv file with this accumulated data and use it to plot a chart,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need the time of day but just the date, you can simply use this:

```
df.created_at = df.created_at.str.split(' ').str[0]  
dfout = df.groupby(['created_at']).count()
dfout.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
finaldf = dfout[['created_at', 'entry_id']]
finaldf.columns = ['Date', 'field2']
finaldf.to_csv('outputfile.csv', index=False)
```

The first line will split the `created_at` column at the space between the date and time. The `.str[0]` means it will only keep the first part of the split (which is the date).
The second line groups them by date and gives you the count.
When writing to csv, if you do not want the index to show (as in your pic), then use `index=False`. If you want the index, then just leave that portion out.

Comment: So this works to sum all of field2 values with same date (excluding time). But how do I export just these 2 columns into a new file? With created_at column being titled "Date", and the "field2" column titled Time. Appreciate your help. I have been looking at tutorials since yesterday to figure this out, and decided to ask on here as a last resort. Again, sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I adjusted the answer to address your last question.

Comment: So i tried that, but I first got a error saying name 'dfout' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, line 2 has been adjusted to correct that error. If all works well, please accept my answer and upvote. I'm new here and could use the rep.

Comment: Correction, seems to be working. Much thanks. You are a savior.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse your date right:

```
df["date_string"] = df["created_at"].str.split(" ").str[0]
df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_string"])
# You can chose to drop earlier columns

# Now you just want to groupby with the date and apply the aggregation/function you want to 
df = df.groupby(["date_time"]).sum("field2").reset_index() # for example
df.to_csv("abc.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: So the .csv is a file extracted from a server that receives pings from a micro-controller every minute and logs this. This value is entered under the field2 column. So I need to add all field2 values with the same date and export this data to a separate file, where the sum of all field2 values is the total time for that date in particular.

Comment: Then my answer is correct. Please use it, upvote and select :)

Comment: For some reason it get a error:   KeyError: "['created_at' 'date_string'] not found in axis"

Comment: KeyError: "['created_at' 'date_string'] not found in axis"

Comment: @NavitJammu fixed that. Now try

Comment: I still get an error: TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Nickos solution below seems to work. However I need to extract those two columns of information to a new .csv file. With the new column names as mentioned above (Date and Time). Where time is the sum of all field2 values for a given date (excluding timestamp).